# How to create a Java Standalone Application

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, runnable

I have an Eclipse project and I need to export it as a standalone Java application that runs, at least, on Windows, using its own JRE (embedding other features such as splash screen, application icon etc...).

I used to create a runnable JAR file from Eclipse, choosing the **Extract required libraries into generated JAR** option. Then I use a cross-platform tool for wrapping the JAR in lightweight Windows native executables (.exe). This tool allows me to specify the JRE to be used, the splash screen displayed while the application loads, the icon to be used, some product info etc...

The problem is that, with very big and complex projects, that refer to lots of libraries, even if I can compile and run the application in a while inside Eclipse, when I create the JAR file it takes forever to load (and it's even worse with the final EXE file).

Since I'm not an IT expert and thus not very aware of these topics, I'd like to ask if there is any other/better way to create deliverable applications without loosing the advantages of an EXE file (especially **it is mandatory for me to embed a private JRE** and assign an icon to the product).

Comment: If you have big projects with a lot of dependencies, I would recommend using a build-tool like Gradle or Maven to handle the building process.

See this link about bundling a jar file using Gradle:
https://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/

Comment: How long is "forever" on modern hardware?

Comment: (1) Check the used memory options `-Xmx`. (2) Profiling the application to search for bottle necks never hurts. (3) Use FindBugs or such to give a health check. In this case for memory leaks and related performance problems.

Comment: @Henry forever means to me more than a couple of minutes, since the application in Eclipse is loaded in a couple of second. Anyway, in this case it takes more than 20 minutes to open.

Comment: @qantik thank you for the link. I need to study it carefully to understand if it can solve my problems.

Comment: @JoopEggen how can I check the `-Xmx`? I set it as 512mb but, just to be sure. Moreover, when you talk about bottlenecks and bugs do you mean inside my code? In this case I can't understand why when I compile the project from Eclipse I don't have bugs or performance issues...

Comment: a couple of seconds and 20 min is a significant difference. Maybe a virus scanner is contributing to this ...

Comment: The memory seems fine. Eclipse has everything compiled and loaded fast. FindBugs detects more than simple bugs, memory leaks, some race conditions I believe, exception hiding and such. I bet if you do not find something interesting at least, you must be using a competitor. But on the original problem: it might be an other XML parser (gotten via the SPI, the factory). If the application is an eclipse RCP that would explain the difference too. But I guess it is swing application?

Comment: @JoopEggen yes it is a swing application.

Comment: (Swing has a JFileChooser that is slow on `new`.)

Comment: @JoopEggen actually I create a `new` `JFileChooser`, but not at application startup. Should it matters?

Comment: Then not, but in a JFrame initialising a JFileChooser is such an easily made "error." XSLT or XML with validation (loading of DTD files!) can be slow too. Without profiling it is a bit hard to tell. It could be a resource file that is found in eclipse but not deployed, or whatever. Windows/eclipse: case-insensitive resource names, packed in jar/exe: case-sensitive. Sorry & good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use **[Maven](http://maven.apache.org/index.html)** or **[Gradle](https://gradle.org/)** to build your application instead of Eclipse. You will have a better dependecy management.

Also, you should use **[Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)** to create a Windows Exe laucher for your application. It contains an embedded JRE so your application can run in standalone.

Comment: Launch4J is the tool I'm currently using for wrapping the jars, but it creates very slow-to-open .exe applications (compared to the Eclipse Java application). I'll have a look to Maven and Gradle to understand if they can help, thank you very much for the hint. Can I import existing project as I do in Eclipse with them?